# Position section element below the header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the section element to start from 1px below the header element, so I set its top property as in the css code. I thought I was doing every thing correctly but it is still starting half way into the header element.

Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    top: calc(1.5em + 1px);
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` are properties that only work when you have a `position` property. `section` does not have any `position` so the `top` would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is when the element is fixed, then it gets taken out of the "flow" of the document.

You can fix it with adding a margin-top to the section area and removing the top;

```css
section {
    margin-top: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` in `section` top is not render without `position`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    top: calc(1.5em + 1px);
    background-color: red;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do.

**First:** Give following css to remove default margin and padding of browser.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Second:** Give `margin-top: 1px;` to section instead of `top`.

**[Check how top works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    background-color: red;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ketan, after header 1px;

Answer (score 1):

remove **top** from the section and add the **margin-top** for it

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header > button {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top: 0;
}

label.pageTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 5em);
    text-align: center;
    color: turquoise;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

section {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top:45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body >
<header>
    <button class="menuLeft" type="button" >&#9776;</button>
    <label class="pageTitle">Title of Page</label>
    <button class="menuRight" type="button">&#8942;</button>
</header>

<section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci, aliquid, aspernatur culpa dicta dignissimos dolore error expedita ipsa maiores neque non, officia omnis provident quae quidem recusandae rem vero?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem facere laborum magnam maxime numquam reprehenderit soluta vitae voluptas. Consequuntur ea exercitationem ipsa officiis, placeat provident quibusdam sequi velit voluptate!lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam architecto corporis doloribus laboriosam necessitatibus non quae, saepe temporibus! Accusamus ducimus eligendi eos fugit ipsam itaque numquam officiis praesentium repellat saepe?lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab consequuntur eum facilis incidunt laudantium nisi non quis sapiente, vero voluptates. Animi deleniti et, fugit laborum molestiae nisi non possimus qui.lorem</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `<section>` is set to `position: relative`

Please see the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p741tbxx/

```
section {
    top: calc(1.5em + 1px);
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
```